# Bash. Get max columns and lines of a maximized terminal

Tags: bash, size, screen, lines, xterm

in my bash script I'm trying to open xterm windows with fixed positions depending of the screen size. I know how to get resolution using xdpyinfo and is useful to set the position of the xterms windows but my problem is to know the columns and the lines of that xterm windows.

Is possible to know the total columns and lines availables in a screen? because I want to create for example a xterm terminal window using a quarter of the screen, which is the half of x axis and the half of y axis... how to know the total available columns and lines to perform the calculation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you maximize your terminal try `tput cols` and `tput lines`.

Comment: yeah, I know that, but how can I maximize the window from the script? even if this is possible... is there a method to know that without opening a terminal, maximizing it, getting the cols and lines with tput and then close it?

Comment: It depends on your terminal. If you want to start xterm maximized you can type `term -maximized` or use this in your bash script. Maybe you can read this in your man pages for your specific terminal. Then you can calculate by your one. If you try this with different screens you can map this or put this in a bash script which run once to calculate this.

Comment: I'm thinking in create a relation of "ratio" for most used linux distros... which is resolution / maxcolumns and let it hardcoded in the script... this ratios should be calculated testing and testing and testing... I can't see more elegant solution :/

Comment: I agree with you, but there are so many terminals in the wild. Take a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/210182/how-to-check-which-terminal-emulator-is-being-currently-used)